# Unresponsive Script Error Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am in a middle of creating a website where we need to use a lot of script work. But due to extensive data load as we are loading the listing for youtube the browser hangs up due to unresponsive script error.

The data is being loaded using AJAX.

Can any one suggest how to tackle this issue?

Your suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

J

Comment: Could you bring here the code that fails, please?

Comment: I think we will need to more information from you in order to provide a truly helpful answer. Can you post an example of the code that makes the AJAX call? At the very least, can you tell us wether the call is synchronous or asynchronous? How many elements are you creating/adding to the page. How much memory is the browser using?

Comment: @dgvid In case i am using the AJAX so obviously the call will be asynchronous. And regarding the code, most of the work is done using the ajax as the website has a heavy GUI. So what my major concern is to optimize the scripts to behave properly.

Comment: @CodemasterGabriel It's going to be nearly impossible to "optimize the scripts" without seeing them.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the  dom.max_script_run_time and dom.max_chrome_script_run_time values, but it means the warning comes less often.

The best thing that you can do just find the root of the problem. I think you use Firefox, so if the script runs too slowly and long just click the Stop Script button and go to the error console.

[More info are here.](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Unresponsive_Script_Warning#Finding_the_source_of_the_problem)

Comment: This is the user based format to change the max_script_run_time in firefox but i am asking the question on the developer perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing details, I can offer only these generalizations. Maybe one or more will help:

- The jQuery .ajax call takes an option to make the call synchronous. That, combined with an unresponsive server, would cause the problem you describe. So, make sure you haven't mistakenly set that option.
- On some browsers, FF at least, running out of memory causes an unresponsive script error. Chrome has a nice feature in which you can open a new tab, enter "about:memory" into the address bar, and a get a quick overview of how much memory other Chrome tabs/windows are using. See anything outrageous here?
- On FF and IE, I have seen an infinite loop cause an unresponsive script error. Use a profiler, to detect this condition.
- A profiler, like the one build in to Firebug for example, can help you pin down where in your script the problem is occurring. Knowing that, you can look for opportunities to break up the code into smaller operations. *E.g.*, if you are processing a large amount of data, perhaps you could make a recursive call a setTimeout handler to process chunks of data at a time.